# Understanding the concepts of sounds analysis

Tags: sound, sampling, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to understand many concepts behind sound analysis. Here's what I'm trying to understand:

- What's sound & sound wave?
- What's sampling and hertz? And how to do sampling? (starting from basic trigonometry to sampling)
- What's FFT?
- What's a spectrogram?

I tried to look on Google for a tutorial that completely explains those ideas in a good order as I explained them, but I failed. Also looking into books about digital signal processing I found that it needs a high learning rate to achieve what I need. I'm really looking into just the basic ideas behind sound analysis and how computer sees and deals with sounds.

If you could explain the concepts in this question with prober graphs I would be super thankful. Otherwise I would also appreciate any links that would direct me to good tutorials.

Comment: Sampling of an analog signal doesn't related with trigonometry.

Comment: Wow! Theses are a lot of question. Answering all of them in one single answer would require a lot of effort... First, I suggest that you split your question into smaller chunks. Second, this in more a set of question about signal processing. Which might be off topics here because it's not about electronics, but about math related to audio signal processing.

Comment: Are you really saying there is nothing on _the entire internet_ that explains any of these concepts? Have you tried Wikipedia?

Comment: To be fair, actually performing the Fast Fourier transform using a microcontroller is something I have done. And it involves a pretty fair understanding of trigonometry. And yeah, the stuff for this topic is explained in rather high-level academic terms. @AlexTwain, though, make sure you're doing the work to make this worthwhile.

Comment: An explanation of "hertz" might be a few lines and a picture. Easy for this site BUT moving on the explain what FFT is (given you don't know what hertz is) is a mammoth task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound, as people experience it, is a traveling pressure wave caused by something that moved. Your brain reinterprets that pressure as something meaningful, and can separate sounds that come from different sources and in different directions - which is pretty cool considering we only have the two ear drums.

These pressure waves usually shake high and low - if they don't, well, that's actually just an explosion. How many times it goes high and low in a second is its frequency. Frequency is measured in hertz, which just means "how many times per second this happens". Well, roughly.

Computers do NOT work like brains. They can't just tell that different sounds are present. They can really only get how high the pressure is in the wave one point at a time. But they can do it *really really fast*. That's called sampling.

The FFT is the Fast Fourier Transform. It is NOT a simple thing to understand how to do, really. But *what* it does, is use math to break down the samples that we took with a computer into all of its parts so that the computer can find *different* frequencies hiding in the sound. Its a complicated high speed computerized way of doing exactly what your brain does every time you have to listen to two people try to talk to you at the same time, or tell the difference between a cat's meow and a dog's bark.

When the Fast Fourier Transform is done, we now know how strong each of the pieces of the sound were, more or less while that sound is being made, because its very fast. Have you ever seen those little bars on the front of a stereo that jump up and down with the music? That is one kind of a spectrogram. Each bar or line indicates how strong each different band of frequencies is, and we got that straight from the FFT.

I've tried my best - ask more questions. Don't be discouraged. It's tough to get started.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you thank you SO MUCH!!! This was really helpful!!!